# how to determine whether the series is absolutely con-vergent,conditionally convergent or divergent

Tags: real-analysis

In each of the following cases, state whether the series is absolutely con-vergent, conditionally convergent (i.e. convergent but not absolutely conver-gent) or divergent.
a. $ \sum_{n=1}^∞ (−1)^n (1/2n + 3)$
b.$ \sum_{n=1}^∞ (−1)^n (n/(n + 2))$
.
c. $ \sum_{n=1}^∞ (−1)^n (n \log n/e^n)$

I am completely stuck on this.could not guess which theorem will be applicable for which one.thanks for your kind help

Answer (score 1):

a. Use the [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test): $a_n = 1/(2n + 3) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$ monotonically hence the series in "a." converges. But $|1 / (2n + 3)| \ge |1 / (3n + 3)|$ and $1/3 \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1 / (n + 1)$ is the harmonic series and diverges hence the series in "a." does not converge absolutely.

b. Since $|n / (n + 2)|$ is monotonically increasing, "b." does not converge absolutely. If you discard the negative terms: $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n n}{n+2} \geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n}{2n + 2} = 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n+1}$$
The sum converges if and only if the corresponding integral exists:
$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{x}{x+1} dx = \infty$$

Hence "b." does also not converge.

c. To test for absolute convergence apply the [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test). You will see that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_{n+1}/a_n| = \frac{1}{e} < 1$.